# Best way to implement something like TimerTask in Android

Tags: android, timer, resume, timertask

I know this question is somewhat beaten but i haven't been able to get an answer to my specific problem.

I have several components that use `TimerTask` that i need to pause and resume afterwards.

What is the best way to do it? (Even if not with the Timer/TimerTask system)

Thanks in advance
JQCorreia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have several components that use TimerTask that i need to pause and resume afterwards.
>   What is the best way to do it?

Use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). With this you can post a `Runnable` to run using [`Handler.post(yourRunnable`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and remove it by using [`Handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29). There are also methods in the API to make the `Runnable` execute after a specified delay.

Combine these two methods to implement a pause / resume function in your application.

Comment: Thanks m8! I've implemented a simple Timer using handler messages that executes a runnable. Simple clean and quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? TimerTask is actually pretty old and has been part of java since 1.3. The newer preferred method is using executor service. Look at using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Here is another question with a similar answer [Pausing/stopping and starting/resuming Java TimerTask continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098642/pausing-stopping-and-starting-resuming-java-timertask-continuously)