# Pause CountDown timer Android

Tags: android, countdown

I'm making a game for android which has a countdown. The countdown works perfectly, but the problem is that when I pause the game (I stop painting the surfaceview), the countdown continues on.

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {       
        timer = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
    }
}.start();
```

How can I pause the countdown?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362014/countdown-timer-with-pause-and-resume

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663508/794088

Comment: A proper solution would be to write your own version of `CountDownTimer` that supports pause & resume. Don't use `TimerTask` since that's creating a background thread and you must not touch the UI from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by making a variable timer

```
 static int timer = 60000;
```

Paas this as an argument:

```
CountdownTimer ct = new CountdownTimer(timer,1000){
     Update your timer variable every time the countdown ticks.
     Timer = timer-1000;
     .
     .

}
```

Now whenever you want to *pause your timer*

```
ct.cancel();
```

And *start* it whenever you want by calling

```
ct.start;
```