# How to change the way that timer schedules in TimerTask?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Here is the code snippet:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //change the timer rate of scheduleAtFixedRate here
    }

};

//every 10 sec
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), 10000);
```

Could anyone tell me how to change the rate of timer to `t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), 30000)` in method `run` from `TimerTask` instance?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify an existing schedule, but you can [`cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) the TimerTask that's executing, and reschedule it for the new period.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to reschedule the timer that is already running. You need to cancel the current task and reschedule it with your new interval.

[Pausing/stopping and starting/resuming Java TimerTask continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098642/pausing-stopping-and-starting-resuming-java-timertask-continuously)