# Java Swing Timer cannot be paused?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, 2d

Is there anyway to pause a Java Swing Timer, i'm planning to implement a feature in this java 2D environment and want the ability to pause the movement graphics.

Comment: Duplicate? [Pausing/stopping and starting/resuming Java TimerTask continuously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098642/pausing-stopping-and-starting-resuming-java-timertask-continuously/2098678#2098678)

Answer (score 0):

Timers cannot be paused. You'll have to add the functionality yourself. Here's an example that pauses the timer on mouse over:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Anappletthatcountsdownfromaspecifiedtime.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stop()` method and then `restart()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pause a Swing Timers once started. But you can make use of Timer class `setDelay(int delay)` to delay  between successive action events